# SQL Join with same column, different tables, different values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have got a few tables which I am trying to join.

I just don't know of a way of doing what I need, it is a bit hard to explain so I will show you the query so far:

```
SELECT  exp_channel_data.field_id_102,
        exp_channel_data.field_id_104,
        exp_channel_data.field_id_126,
        exp_channels.deft_status
FROM exp_channel_data
  INNER JOIN exp_channels
    ON exp_channels.channel_id = exp_channel_data.channel_id
  INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles
    ON exp_channels.channel_id = exp_channel_titles.channel_id
WHERE exp_channels.channel_id = 18
AND exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 19
```

The bit that doesn't work is the AND exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 19

The issue is that I get a 0 result set back. Yet I know that both columns have data in them. Although they are totally separate data-sets.

> exp_channels

contains all the data such as Day, Time, Price etc

> exp_channel_titles

contains all of the title information

But I need to combine the two together so I can get a result set of:

"Title, Day, Teacher, Time" etc

So I was just wondering if anyone had a solution on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of results you want to obtain? I think that this query shows 0 rows...

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work ? Your query is not returning what you want ? It doesn't seem too complicated, so you should maybe try to explain...

Comment: Updated the question to be a bit more clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL join issue with multiple columns with the same name but different value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079558/sql-join-issue-with-multiple-columns-with-the-same-name-but-different-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using inner join, so all the `channel_id` of one row should be same.

Do you mean `OR` ?

```
SELECT  exp_channel_data.field_id_102,
        exp_channel_data.field_id_104,
        exp_channel_data.field_id_126,
        exp_channels.deft_status
FROM exp_channel_data
  INNER JOIN exp_channels
    ON exp_channels.channel_id = exp_channel_data.channel_id
  INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles
    ON exp_channels.channel_id = exp_channel_titles.channel_id
WHERE exp_channels.channel_id = 18
OR exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 19
```

OR you could use `IN`.

```
WHERE exp_channels.channel_id IN (18, 19)
```

Comment: Sorry I think it was my fault that I didn't explain it correctly, but that isn't what I need, I have updated the question to TRY and explain a bit better

Comment: @DarkMantis You don't get result is because channel_id can be 18 and 19 in same time, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah I need to get channel_id from exp_channels where the id is 18 AND i need to get the channel_id from the exp_channel_titles where the ID is 19.

I don't know if this is possible

Comment: @DarkMantis This is not how join work, you join two tables and then say they should have different id, that's not possible.

Comment: So there is no easy way of doing this? I am not very good at SQL (as you can see) so I am just looking for a push in the right direction