# SQL join issue with multiple columns with the same name but different value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have a bit of an issue with my SQL statement. It is a bit hard to explain so I will show you:

```
SELECT  exp_channel_data.field_id_102,
        exp_channel_data.field_id_104,
        exp_channel_data.field_id_126,
        exp_channels.deft_status
FROM exp_channel_data
  INNER JOIN exp_channels
    ON exp_channels.channel_id = exp_channel_data.channel_id
  INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles
    ON exp_channels.channel_id = exp_channel_titles.channel_id
WHERE exp_channels.channel_id = 18
AND exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 19
```

The bit that doesn't work is the AND exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 19

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've joined on `exp_channels.channel_id = exp_channel_titles.channel_id`
and are filtering on

```
exp_channels.channel_id = 18 
exp_channel_titles.channel_id = 19
```

so there can never be any results